# Connection to DynamoDB hangs in 'scan'?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We're mounting a connection to DynamoDB and it hangs on first connection.  We have traced it to a specific call to the service.

We have

```
this.docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
```

Followed by the following code (which is inside a Promise):

```
this.docClient.scan(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < data.Items.length; i += 1) {
          data.Items[i]._id = data.Items[i].id;
        }
        resolve(data.Items);
      });
```

The callback to `docClient.scan` never gets called.  I've traced down into the internals and arrived at `node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js`

```
 send: function send(callback) {

    if (callback) {
      // append to user agent
      this.httpRequest.appendToUserAgent('callback');
      this.on('complete', function (resp) {
        callback.call(resp, resp.error, resp.data);
      });
    }
    this.runTo();

    return this.response;
  },
```

I suppose this call just never returns.

We've set up all the tokens correctly, as far as I know -- how should we proceed to debug this and understand where we're going wrong?   Thanks for any clues!

Comment: Does your client have network connectivity to DynamoDB? Does a simple awscli invocation (e.g. `aws dynamodb list-tables`) work in the same environment?

Comment: My co-worker says yes, there is connection to dynamodb

Comment: OK, then make an API call that has no potential to take a long time, such as `const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB(); await ddb.describeTable(...).promise()` PS you should consider using the `.promise()` features of the SDK, rather than callbacks.

Comment: scan does call its callback. For sure. I've used it multiple times. the problem is somewhere else. either in the params that you pass or in the way your program is treating the promise that you create and then use inside the callback. Please post the parts of your code around the `this.docClient.scan(params, (err, data) => { ...` call.

Comment: @jarmod  -- The issue seems to be security.  I tried 'listTables' right next to this call and got the error 'The security token included in the request is invalid.'  I have a valid security token in ~/.aws/credentials -- how do I connect this to the call?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer lay in the `~/.aws/credentials` file.

The credentials <s>you download from your AWS dashboard</s> I downloaded from our internal dashboard come in a file that looks like this:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = aaaaaaaaa
aws_secret_access_key = bbbbbbbbbb
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN = ccccccccccccc
```

I noticed that `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` was different, that is, capitalised, so I changed it to lower case and it worked.  So there seems to be a problem with the dashboard generating the credentials file.

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = aaaaaaaaa
aws_secret_access_key = bbbbbbbbbb
aws_session_token = ccccccccccccc
```

The one thing I don't understand is those instances when `~/.aws/credentials` is badly configured sometimes it doesn't return an error, but simply doesn't return at all.  That seems to me another problem.

Comment: Which dashboard are you referring to here? I’m not aware of anywhere in the AWS console that would return STS credentials in this form (especially not mixed-case).

Comment: @jarmod You are right -- it's an internal dashboard that we pass through in the login process to get to the AWS dashboard.  I've not really used AWS before so assumed it was part of the AWS process.  Edited to reflect that.